# Heap Memory Allocaton for same variable

Tags: java, string, jvm, string-pool

```java
String str = "Hello";

str = "Hello";
```

Above statements will create two objects on heap or same object will be return by jvm?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `"Hello"` is a constant in the `String` pool. Only one object is involved here.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool this article can help in understanding how does string works.

Comment: When you use double quotes to create a String, it first looks for String with the same value in the String pool, if found it just returns the reference else it creates a new String in the pool and then returns the reference. So, here only one object will be created by jvm.

Comment: *At most* one object, as there could already be an existing string before the execution of this code.

Answer (score 0):

String str = "Hello"
 it will go to SCP memory. like str pointing to your String variable"hello". there is only one object.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before Answer a question here. This type of answer should be in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are stored in the SpringPool.

In your above example, "Hello" is a string pool and there will be only one reference of this object in the string pool. Hence there will be only one object in the memory.